# Inter-religious marriages in Islam

Tags: nikah

I am a non-Muslim and my girlfriend is a Muslim. We want to get married. Initially, as expected, her parents opposed. But they are ready to accept me now on a condition. (After consultation with their spiritual leader) they have asked me to convert to Islam and only then they would allow me to marry their daughter.

My girlfriend is a good Muslim and that is one of the reasons I love her. But I am an atheist and I do not want to convert to Islam (or any religion for that matter). Is their any way we can get married and still be who we really are? Is it at all true ( what her parents are saying) that Islam does not allow inter-religious marriages?

P.S.: We are aware about the last resort and we can always go ahead without thinking of anyone, but I do not want her to do that.
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Islam doesn't allow anyone to forcibly convert. If you really think that following islam can give you peace and prosperity then you can convert, otherwise it is very difficult for the relationship you are looking for.

What I would suggest you is that you try to follow Islam for only a month. Strictly and following all the rules. This will also help you to come more closer to your would be spouse. And I am sure you will understand why people ask you to follow Islam.

May Allah guide you and support you in your future endeavour.

Comment: Please focus on the part of question which is directly relevant to this site which is a site on questions about Islam not muslim life problems. That part is:  "Is it at all true ( what her parents are saying) that Islam does not allow inter-religious marriages?"

Comment: @iOS Dev And what if after one month, he finds Islam is not for him, and he goes back to atheism, what is to be his fate?

Comment: @Seeker: Then I would say this relationship is not for him. Atleast he can do it for his girlfriend. If the girl can, against all odd, fight with her family  for him, this is the least he can do it for her. Everybody knows how difficult it is for a muslim girl to stay away from her family married to a non-muslim.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: http://islamqa.info/en/21380

Key notes are:

> It is not permissible for a Muslim woman to marry a non-Muslim from
>   any other religion, whether from among the Jews or Christians, or any
>   other kaafir religion. It is not permissible for her to marry a Jew, a
>   Christian, a Magian, a communist, an idol-worshipper, etc.

And just so you know, there are strict warnings in Islam against illegitimate relations before marriage.

I hope you accept the correct path some time.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is the very incompatibility of your views wont hold a family together.
The equations of your relationship itself are dysfunctional, based on a just some attractions. They will in time fizzle and there wont be any social structure to hold it. Your relationship is bound for failures.
There is a study on American families in this regard already that I have read, where Christian beliefs with Atheist spouse were studied. Most ended up a failure over time, creating deep psychological traumas for both involved.